# How to save data from QSpinBox into variable after clicking button?

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm in the process of making an alarm clock GUI. My GUI has options to "Create Alarm", "Remove Alarm", and "View Alarms". In the Create Alarm option, I made a QDialog window consisting of 2 SpinBoxes (for a 24 hour clock) with a Cancel and OK button.

I'd like to have the user select the time they'd like, say 10:30, then to have that specific time saved into a variable and/or append it to an empty array after the user presses the OK button. So then I could hopefully carry that variable/array over into the "Remove Alarm" and "View Alarms" portions. Is this possible or should I go about it a different way?

Here is my code so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import datetime


# Start with empty array that will store appended alarms

alarms = []


class Window( QWidget ):

    def __init__( self ):
        super(Window, self).__init__() 
        self.initUI()


    def initUI( self ):

        self.setGeometry( 300, 300, 500, 600 )
        self.setWindowTitle( "My Alarm Clock GUI" )
        self.label = QLabel( self )
        self.label.setText( "<h1>Alarm Clock</h1>" )
        self.label.setAlignment( Qt.AlignCenter )


        self.b1 = QPushButton( self )
        self.b1.setText( "Create New Alarm" )
        self.b1.clicked.connect( self.create_alarm_clicked )

        self.b2 = QPushButton( self )
        self.b2.setText( "Remove Alarm" )
        self.b2.clicked.connect( self.remove_alarm_clicked )

        self.b3 = QPushButton( self )
        self.b3.setText( "View Alarms" )
        self.b3.clicked.connect( self.view_alarm_clicked )

        self.b4 = QPushButton( self )
        self.b4.setText( "Quit" )
        self.b4.clicked.connect( self.quit_clicked )


        self.label_image = QLabel( self )
        self.pixmap = QPixmap( "clock_pic_copy.png" )
        self.label_image.setPixmap( self.pixmap )
        self.label_image.setAlignment( Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignHCenter )


        self.date_label = QLabel( self )
        self.date_label.setAlignment( Qt.AlignCenter )
        self.time_label = QLabel( self )
        self.time_label.setAlignment( Qt.AlignCenter )


        timer = QTimer( self )
        timer.timeout.connect( self.DateAndTime )
        timer.start( 1000 )


        layout = QVBoxLayout( )
        layout.setAlignment( Qt.AlignCenter )
        layout.addWidget( self.label_image )
        layout.addWidget( self.label )
        layout.addWidget( self.date_label )
        layout.addWidget( self.time_label )
        layout.addWidget( self.b1 )
        layout.addWidget( self.b2 )
        layout.addWidget( self.b3 )
        layout.addWidget( self.b4 )
        self.setLayout(layout)


    def DateAndTime(self):

        current_date = QDate.currentDate()
        current_time = QTime.currentTime()

        # converting QDate & QTime object to string
        label_time = current_time.toString( 'hh:mm:ss' )
        label_date = current_date.toString('m-dd-yyyy')

        # showing it to the label
        self.date_label.setText(label_date)
        self.time_label.setText( label_time )


    # Create Alarm button function
    def create_alarm_clicked( self ):

        # Make QDialogButtonBox a subclass of QDialog
        dialog = QDialog(self)
        dialog.setGeometry( 425, 500, 200, 200 )
        dialog.setWindowTitle( "Create Alarm" )


        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QRect(10, 350, 161, 41))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons( QDialogButtonBox.Cancel |
                                           QDialogButtonBox.Ok )
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName( "buttonBox" )


        self.create_alarm_label = QLabel( self )
        self.create_alarm_label.setText( "<h3>Please select time for the alarm:</h3>" )

        self.create_alarm_text = QLabel(self)
        self.create_alarm_text.setText( "Note: This app uses 24-hour time.")


        # Spinbox for hours
        sbox = QSpinBox( self )
        sbox.valueChanged.connect( self.updateLabel )
        sbox.setMaximum(23)
        self.s_label = QLabel( '0', self )


        # Spinbox for minutes
        sbox2 = QSpinBox(self)
        sbox2.valueChanged.connect( self.updateLabel)
        sbox2.setMaximum(59)
        self.s2_label = QLabel( '0', self )


        # Inner layout which holds the Spinboxes
        dialog.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        dialog.horizontalLayout.addWidget(sbox)
        dialog.horizontalLayout.addWidget(sbox2)


        # Outer layout for "Create Alarm" dialog
        dialog.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        dialog.layout.setAlignment( Qt.AlignCenter )
        dialog.layout.addWidget( self.create_alarm_label )
        dialog.layout.addWidget(self.create_alarm_text)
        dialog.layout.addLayout(dialog.horizontalLayout)
        dialog.layout.addWidget( self.buttonBox )


        dialog.setLayout( dialog.layout )     


        dialog.exec_()  


    # Updates the Spin Box
    def updateLabel( self, value ):

        self.s_label.setText( str( value ) )
        self.s2_label.setText( str( value ) )



    # View Alarm function
    def view_alarm_clicked( self, value ):

        global alarms

        self.view_messagebox = QMessageBox( self )
        self.view_messagebox.setGeometry( 425, 500, 400, 400 )
        self.view_messagebox.setWindowTitle( "View Alarms" )
        self.view_messagebox.setStandardButtons( QMessageBox.Cancel | QMessageBox.Ok )
        self.view_messagebox.setDefaultButton( QMessageBox.Ok )


        if len(alarms) == 0:
            self.view_messagebox.setText( "<h3>You have no alarms</h3>" )

            self.view_messagebox.show()
            self.view_messagebox.exec()



        if len(alarms) > 0:

            self.view_messagebox.setText( "<h3>You have alarms for:</h3> " + alarms)

            self.view_messagebox.show()
            self.view_messagebox.exec()


    # Remove Alarm function
    def remove_alarm_clicked( self ):

        global alarms

        self.remove_messagebox = QMessageBox( self )
        self.remove_messagebox.setGeometry( 425, 500, 400, 400 )
        self.remove_messagebox.setWindowTitle( "View Alarms" )
        self.remove_messagebox.setStandardButtons( QMessageBox.Cancel | QMessageBox.Ok )
        self.remove_messagebox.setDefaultButton( QMessageBox.Ok )

        if len(alarms) == 0:
            self.remove_messagebox.setText( "<h3>You have no alarms to delete</h3>" )

            self.remove_messagebox.show()
            self.remove_messagebox.exec()

        elif len(alarms) > 0:
            self.remove_messagebox.setText( "<h3>Please select alarm you'd like to delete</h3>" )

            self.remove_messagebox.show()
            self.remove_messagebox.exec()


    # Quit Button functions
    def quit_clicked( self ):
        self.close()


    def ring_alarm( self ):
        pass


def run():
    app = QApplication( [ ] )
    GUI = Window()  
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )

run()
```

The dialog of the Create Alarm portion of GUI:

[image: The dialog of the Create Alarm portion of GUI]

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: What I'd like to do is have the user pick a time. Then when they press the OK button, the time they selected will be saved in either a variable or be appended into an empty array, so I could use that variable/array in the other functions (Remove Alarm, View Alarms). I just dont know how to go about that since I'm new to Python/PyQt

Comment: @Sebastian The code in `create_alarm_clicked` should go in a separate subclass of `QDialog`, with all the widgets set as attributes (i.e. just like you did with the main window class). Then you can create an instance of that class in `create_alarm_clicked` and access the values like this: `dialog = CreateAlarmDialog(); if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted: hour = dialog.sbox.value(); ... etc `.

Comment: @ekhumoro ok I will do so. Thank you for the detailed comment.